# combining multiple values & sorting

Tags: python, pandas

I have below detailed invoice data.

```
+------------+---------------+--------+-----+-------+------------+-------------+
| Invoice No | Invoice Total | Item # | qty | price | Item Total | Inventory # |
+------------+---------------+--------+-----+-------+------------+-------------+
|          1 |            42 |    123 |   1 |    10 |         10 |           0 |
|          1 |            42 |    234 |   2 |    12 |         24 |          10 |
|          1 |            42 |    345 |   1 |     8 |          8 |           0 |
|          2 |           224 |    123 |   3 |    10 |         30 |           4 |
|          2 |           220 |    234 |   2 |    12 |         24 |           3 |
|          2 |           220 |    345 |   8 |     1 |          8 |           0 |
|          2 |           220 |    456 |  10 |    12 |        120 |           2 |
|          2 |           220 |    567 |   7 |     6 |         42 |           4 |
|          3 |            34 |    123 |   1 |    10 |         10 |          10 |
|          3 |            34 |    234 |   2 |    12 |         24 |           0 |
|          4 |            30 |    123 |   1 |    10 |         10 |           0 |
|          4 |            30 |    234 |   2 |    12 |         24 |           3 |
+------------+---------------+--------+-----+-------+------------+-------------+
```

for each unique individual `Invoice No`, I want to concatenate the `Inventory #` & replace the column with concatenated & sorted values ( ascending from Left to Right). Also any duplicate values should be removed. eg. `Invoice No - 2` has `Inventory # - 4` duplicated twice.

My desired Result is as below

```
+------------+---------------+--------+-----+-------+------------+-------------+
| Invoice No | Invoice Total | Item # | qty | price | Item Total | Inventory # |
+------------+---------------+--------+-----+-------+------------+-------------+
|          1 |            42 |    123 |   1 |    10 |         10 | 0,10        |
|          1 |            42 |    234 |   2 |    12 |         24 | 0,10        |
|          1 |            42 |    345 |   1 |     8 |          8 | 0,10        |
|          2 |           224 |    123 |   3 |    10 |         30 | 0,2,3,4     |
|          2 |           220 |    234 |   2 |    12 |         24 | 0,2,3,4     |
|          2 |           220 |    345 |   8 |     1 |          8 | 0,2,3,4     |
|          2 |           220 |    456 |  10 |    12 |        120 | 0,2,3,4     |
|          2 |           220 |    567 |   7 |     6 |         42 | 0,2,3,4     |
|          3 |            34 |    123 |   1 |    10 |         10 | 0,10        |
|          3 |            34 |    234 |   2 |    12 |         24 | 0,10        |
|          4 |            30 |    123 |   1 |    10 |         10 | 0,3         |
|          4 |            30 |    234 |   2 |    12 |         24 | 0,3         |
+------------+---------------+--------+-----+-------+------------+-------------+
```

please guide me to solve this..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will do `transform`, `set` will drop duplicate and sort , then just need `join`

```
df['Inventory #']=df.groupby('Invoice No')['Inventory'].\
                      transform(lambda x : ','.join(set(x.astype(str))))
```

Comment: same code just a little changed: `df.groupby('Invoice No')['Inventory #'].transform(lambda x : ','.join(sorted(set(x.astype(str)))))`